# In Powershell is Pip3 the same as Pip

Tags: python, powershell, pip

I'm currently running Windows 10 with only Python 3.8 installed. Is it therefore safe to assume that the `pip3` command is the same as the `pip` command in Powershell?

Hence, is `pip install` the same as `pip3 install` for this instance.

NOTE: I know that `pip3` installs packages specific to Python3 when Python2 and Python3 are both available

Comment: This isn't a PowerShell thing. It is entirely dependent on how you've installed Python and/or Pip. If you have only installed this one version of Python, yes, they are probably the same thing.

Comment: try ```pip --version``` and ```pip3 --version```

Comment: The integer following `pip` is the `python` version associated with the target `pip`.

Comment: @questionerofdy, that worked for me, if you put that into an answer I'll mark it as correct

Comment: @TheLazyScripter, kindasorta. Maybe. But how do you distinguish between Python 3.8 and Python 3.9? What is `pip` with no integer appended? This all depends on how Python was installed, and since OP is asking about a bare `pip` I'm not sure how that comment helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check yourself versions of both pips and also python versions associated with them with the command --version

Try

```
pip --version
```

and compare that to the output of

```
pip3 --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare the results of the commands, might work

```
where pip
where pip3
```

Comment: In powershell it is `where.exe pip`.